# How can I keep a second navbar in the correct location for mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am doing a project using Bootstrap 4 in which I need two navbars, the left one should collapse in small devices but the second one shouldn't.

I managed to do that, but when I open the hamburger menu the right navbar goes to the top of the left one instead of staying fixed in its place.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/csantanna/2xb55q5v/3/#&togetherjs=C48LvOlaNQ

The hamburger menu it's not opening there, but in my files it is.
[This is how it appears when the menu its opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDGGc.png) The problem is the icons below the menu.

[And this is the menu closed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d5GH.png) Notice that the icons are not collapsed.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #e0d9d5;
  font-family: 'barlow', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}

a.nav-item {
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

a.nav-item:hover {
  color: rgba(237, 106, 145, 0.5);
}

a.nav-item.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-btn {
  background: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  color: rgba(237, 106, 145, 0.5);
}

.nav-btn i {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.animated-icon1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animated-icon1 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-icon1 span {
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>


      <!--Navbar-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Collapse button -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
          </button>

          <!-- Collapsible content -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <!-- Links -->
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

              <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Produtos <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"> Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Contato <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Collapsible content -->
          <div class="d-flex flex-row order-2 order-lg-3">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="" autocomplete="on">
              <div class="wrap">
                <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?">
                <button id="search_submit" value="Rechercher" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
              </div>
              <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
              <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!--/.Navbar-->
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, you need to move your form out of the surrounding div (because that's not needed) and put it (in the HTML) immediately after the navbar toggler. Note: For simplicity, I replaced your custom toggler with the standard one.

You then apply the classes `order-lg-last ml-auto` to your form.

`order-lg-last` will re-order the form for screens that are `lg` or larger (i.e. will make it the last item) and `ml-auto` means "margin-left:auto" which will push the form to the right.

On smaller screens, the form will come immediately after the toggler button thus produce the desired effect.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Collapse button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<!--                <div class="animated-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>-->
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <form class="form-inline order-lg-last ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0" action="" autocomplete="on">
            <div class="wrap">
                <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?">
                <button id="search_submit" value="Rechercher" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
            <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
            <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></button>
        </form>

        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <!-- Links -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">

                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Produtos <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#"> Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Contato <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
    </div>
</nav>
<!--/.Navbar-->
```

Also, the `mr-auto` class can be removed from your code because it won't do anything here.